# Unable to compare 2 objects of same type

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim obj As New CMS_Page
Dim comparisonObj As New CMS_Page
```

The assignment

```
obj = db.CMS_Pages.First(Function(s) s.PageID = pageID)
comparisonObj = db.CMS_Pages.First(Function(s) s.PageID = pageID)
```

Somwhere in the middle of my code

```
obj.property = sometextfield.text 'Apparently this also changes the comparisonObj
```

Basically what I'm doing in the end would be

```
if (obj.property = comparisonObj.property) then
//...
end if
```

Why can't i change `obj.Property` without it changing the same property in `comparisonObj.Property`?

Comment: Can we see your entire code?  Where do you assign comparisonObj?

Comment: AdrianWragg -> CMS_Page is a class of many propertys.

roryap -> The assigning is in the above code

Jodrell -> I agree, i just am not familiar with vb.net im a c# coder and don't understand the proper way of coding this in vb

Comment: @DonThomasBoyle -- I don't see `comparisonObj =` anywhere.

Comment: You're assigning both variables to the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably setting "comparisonObj = obj".  You probably want "comparisonObj = obj.Clone()".  You will have to implement the "Clone" method yourself.
If CMS_Page is not under your control, then you can create an extension method to clone it.

Comment: As an extra point, as you've accepted this that means there's an error in your original code - there's no need to have the `New` in `Dim comparisonObj As New CMS_Page`, as this creates an instance of CMS_Page that is never used.

Answer (score 1):

What is the result of

```
obj.ReferenceEquals(comparisonObj)
```

if that is `True` then `obj` **is** `comparisonObj`. You can do the same check more concisely like this,

```
obj Is comparisonObj
```

---

If you have a `VB` background, both variables are **references** to the same object.

If you have a `C` background, both variables are **pointers** to the same object.

essentially, the variable holds an integer value that addresses the object in memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
obj = db.CMS_Pages.First(Function(s) s.PageID = pageID)
comparisonObj = db.CMS_Pages.First(Function(s) s.PageID = pageID)
```

These two lines result in two references to the same object.  Hence, when you do this: `obj.property = sometextfield.text` then `comparisonObj` will also reflect that change.

Comment: Well that makes sense, how do i keep them separate?

Comment: You can't keep them separate.  It's the fundamentals of object oriented programming.

Comment: If you want to keep them separate, you have to create a new object either through a clone method or a constructor.

Comment: How is your `db.CMS_Pages` collection populated?